# Android load testing tool for a single device type, but for thousands of instances

Tags: android, load-testing

I'm wondering if anyone knows a load testing tool/platform, which allows us to upload our Android application, configure it, and then spawn like thousands of virtual instances so we can see how our API holds.

I've been looking at AWS Device Farm, although it seems like that doesn't support to spawn multiple instances of a single device type. Lots of tools offer to test an app on different device types, but that's not what I'm interested in as we have our product running on a fixed device type.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for this.

1. Record your mobile application traffic via [JMeter's built-in proxy server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or through [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) service
2. Configure resulting test script to [add anticipated number of users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)
3. Run the test and analyse results.